# Can i programmatically add a product with a specific id?

Tags: magento

How can I do something like adding a new product with a specified product_id/entity_id ?

```
$newprod = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$newprod->setProductId( 100 ); // how do i make this work
$newprod->setSku(... );
```

Comment: product id is auto incremental. Given the EAV structure of the magento database, if you would try to set the entity_id yourself, there is a very high chance that it would disturb other tables and data may not remain consistant

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($desiredId);

if(!$product){ //here also might be something like $product->getSku()
$product->set.......//set required fields here
$product->setEntityId($desiredId); //we won't mess up things, because product with desired id et not exists
$product->save()
}
```

Comment: Jevgeni, does setEntityId work for you? It does not appear to work in my case.

Comment: there might be simply setId or setProductId, try one of these

Comment: or might be setData('entity_id',$id)